# Powershell For each loop returning same info for each host

Tags: powershell

I'm a novice when it comes to using PowerShell. I am trying to get drive capacity and remaining storage for the C drive from a list of servers. I'm using the following:

```
$Servers = get-content  -Path "C:\temp\serverlist.txt" 

ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {   
    Get-Volume -DriveLetter C  | Format-table
}
```

But, I cannot for the life of me figure out why its returning the same value over and over:

```
DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------      ----
C                        NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                       9.6 GB 149.46 GB



DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------      ----
C                        NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                       9.6 GB 149.46 GB



DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------      ----
C                        NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                       9.6 GB 149.46 GB
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: You're executing the very same command in the body of your `for` loop, without reference to `$server`.

Comment: To target multiple computers with PowerShell remoting, try `Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content C:\temp\serverlist.txt) { Get-Volume -DriveLetter C } | Format-Table`

Comment: If you did this in any shell you are familiar with would you not also actually try to connect to `$Server`?